# how to get the labels of a dataset which is built using ImageDataGenerator for dual input CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

Could someone help me get the labels of validation_set when it gets a pair of images as input and  provides image batches using ImageDataGenerator as following:

```
GEN = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

def two_inputs(generator, X1, X2, batch_size, img_height, img_width):
    U = generator.flow_from_directory(X1,
                                            target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle= False,
                                            class_mode='binary',
                                            seed=1221)
    V = generator.flow_from_directory(X2,
                                            target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle= False,
                                            class_mode='binary',
                                            seed=1221)
    while True:
        X1i = U.next()
        X2i = V.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]   # Yield both images and their mutual label
```

In the following scenario I can get predictions by `preds = base_model.predict_generator(val_flow)` where `val_flow` is:

```
val_flow = two_inputs(generator= GEN,
                      X1 = val_05_dirs,
                      X2 = val_06_dirs,
                      batch_size = batch_size,
                      img_height=img_height,
                      img_width=img_width
                      )
```

I need need to get `fpr` and `tpr` using `fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(LABELS, preds)`.

Therefore I am trying to get the `LABELS` of a full `val_flow` which is accessing `two val_05_dirs` , `val_06_dirs` folders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the dataset and storing the labels in a list?

Comment: No, how would I do that? Because there are two labels (`abnormal` , `normal`) and labels are the names of a folder where corresponding images reside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple code example. You can adapt this example to suit your use case.
**Code:**

```
GEN = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

folder_path = r'C:\Users\Aniket\.keras\datasets\flower_photos'

def two_inputs(generator, X1, X2, batch_size, img_height, img_width):
    U = generator.flow_from_directory(X1,
                                            target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle= False,
                                            class_mode='binary',
                                            seed=1221)
    V = generator.flow_from_directory(X2,
                                            target_size=(img_height, img_width),
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle= False,
                                            class_mode='binary',
                                            seed=1221)
    while True:
        X1i = U.next()
        X2i = V.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]   # Yield both images and their mutual label
        
custom_gen = two_inputs(GEN, folder_path, folder_path, 1000, 256, 256)
```

Here, my `flower_photos` directories contain 5 subdirectories with the names of subdirectories as the label for the image.

**Output:**

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
```

Now iterating over the generator.
**Code:**

```
val_labels = []
for image, labels in custom_gen:
    val_labels += list(labels.astype('int32'))
    break
```

**Note: The loop will run infinitely because this generator, generates an augmented image from your data infinitely.**

If you dont want this make the loop run only for:

```
no_of_times = total_samples / batch_size
```

**Make sure your batch size is divisible by the total no of samples or you will get repeated labels added at the end of your list.**

The labels you get would be integers.
If you want the mappings you can get it by using:

```
mapping = U.class_indices
mapping
```

**Output:**

```
{'daisy': 0, 'dandelion': 1, 'roses': 2, 'sunflowers': 3, 'tulips': 4}
```

Comment: the labels I want to get should come from `val_flow` which is defined by `two_inputs` function. The function itself a custom generator for dual input that yields different batch of labels everytime it is run. I don't think the code you provided could help. Because in your answer it's only one input and not deined in a customized way. Please, note that `two_input` `yield`s `[X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]` as output.

Comment: Can you add a standalone code to generate your issue? Also, do x1 and x2 contain the same number of classes as well as the same no of examples in the specified classes

Comment: I have updated the answer according to your case. See if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `no_of_times` is not an `int` in my case, I can't remove images to make it `int`. Any work around?

Comment: Try `batch_size = 1`,  expensive but if you want to run it just once to get labels you can use it.

Comment: nice way actually. But aren't the images in respective folders trained in `fit_generator` in a shuffled way which consequently make the the list `val_labels` invalid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220959/discussion-between-aniket-bote-and-bit-scientist).

Comment: I accepted the answer as it satisfies what I asked. Though if `the number of samples` for either `train` set or `val` set is different everytime you run it (i.e. k-fold CV) it is not possible to determine the actual numbers in advance. And setting `batch_size` to `1` is not practical as one cannot know when to break the `loop`, again with different number of samples are considered.